# Kendo UI grid select row via selenium web driver

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a UI test for an application that uses a kendo grid. I am using selenium to drive the browser, and I am having trouble selecting a row in the grid.

I have been able to select the correct row like this:

```
IWebElement matterToSelect = MatterToSelectGrid.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[text()='" + matterId + "']/ancestor::tr"));
```

I was hoping to simply call .click() the webElement, but that did not work. So I tried building an action:

```
new Actions(Driver).MoveToElement(matterToSelect).Click().Build().Perform();
```

also no joy. Okay what about selecting it with js?:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("return $(\"tr[data-uid='" + id + "']\").trigger('click');");
```

still nothing, what about a more direct selection just to see if it will work?

```
js.ExecuteScript("return $(\"#sourceGrid > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(3) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)\").click();");
```

grrrr still no luck. So my next thought was perhaps the kendo grid has a select() method I can use? Well it seems yes, but from what I read I also need to re-bind the grid? All the exaples I can find look something like this:

```
$("#sourceGrid").data("kendoGrid").select()
```

but I don't want to re-bind the grid from my test, so I have not tried this. Also, I am not sure what should be in data(), as all the grids are set up using the Html helper method, and use the .dataSource method to bind to action methods. Has anyone one got any better suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay, I did it in the end like this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            js.ExecuteScript(String.Format("return $('td:contains(\"{0}\")').parent().addClass('k-state-selected');", matterId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get me wrong, I am not a fan of XPath but this is easiest way I found to select the first row in a Kendo grid.  I gave my grid the Id of 'ticketGrid'.  I then used Chrome Dev tools to inspect the first row.  You can then right click and select 'Copy XPath' and I got this:

```
//*[@id='ticketGrid']/table/tbody/tr[1]
```

Then in my specFlow tests I have the following:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var firstRow = wait.Until(w => w.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//*@id='ticketGrid']/table/tbody/tr[1]")));
firstRow.Click();
```

Hope this helps